# understand the program's logic

Tags: java

I want to know why we can't write method in method in java and Why will the code not execute

```
public class Quiz{

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Book b = new Book(18);
        Book c = new Book(10);
        c = compare(c, b);
    }

    public static Book compare(Book k, Book m) {
        k.x = 10;
        k = null;
        m.x = 3;
        return m;
    }

    class Book {

        int x = 20;

        public Book(int x) {
            this.x = x;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: is this homework btw? should be tagged as such

Comment: Variable names could do with being more meaningful too!

Comment: Please don't ignore the error messages you got from the compiler. They **are** the answer to your question. If you don't understand the error messages, you should copypaste them literally in your question so that we can explain it for you in layman's terms.

Answer (score 2):

Because your `class Book` is a (non-static) [inner class](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/javaOO/nested.html), which means it must live within an instance of the outer class, your class Quiz.

But you do not create any instance of `Quiz`

Make the Book class static:

```
static class Book {
  ...
```

Or move the class definition outside the Quiz class.

Answer (score 0):

```
static class Book {
```

this will solve the compilation error.

> I want to know why we can't write method in method in java
>   Blockquote

You mean why can't we declare a method inside another?

Answer (score 0):

Because `Book` is a non-static inner class, so it can only be instantiated from non-static methods of `Quiz` (otherwise it wouldn't be able to find the `this` reference if it needed one). But I confess I don't really see what you are trying to achieve here.

Answer (score 0):

You can't compile this programm. The compiler will complain with:

```
Quiz.java:4: non-static variable this cannot be referenced from a static context
```

Which means that class `Book` is contained within `Quiz` and `Quiz` hasn't been instantiated yet.

Thus, you need to instantiate a new Book like this:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    Quiz q = new Quiz();
    Book b = q.new Book(18);
    Book c = q.new Book(10);
    c = compare(c, b);
}
```